# Background image won't scroll with content

Tags: html, css, background-attachment

I am encountering an odd CSS issue that is a real headscratcher for me. No matter what CSS I apply, my background image will not scroll with the content on the page. This is what I've set as the body CSS:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center top;
background-attachment: scroll;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-o-background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100% auto;
background-image: url('http://sigurros.s3.amazonaws.com/images/tour/sigur-smoke-bg3.jpg');
overflow: scroll;
```

But the background image always stays fixed on scroll. Page URL: http://sigur-ros.co.uk/tour

Any ideas?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

In *reset.css* you have `overflow : auto`

After removing this, the background scrolls with the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `overflow: scroll` under `body` styles, to `overflow: visible`.